# How to properly run a maven web project in IDEA?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I'm a novice in using maven and idea. I passed throught all intuitive steps to run web project but have got 404 page (this application works well if I use as a simple web project in Idea). The pom file is below:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.home.myapp</groupId>
 <artifactId>MyApp</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <name>MyApp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <properties>
<spring.version>3.1.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
<project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
  <dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency> 
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId> 
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId> 
    <version>${spring.version}</version> 
</dependency> 
<dependency>    
    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>  
    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>  
    <version>1.1.1</version>  
</dependency>
<dependency>    
    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>  
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>  
    <version>2.3</version>  
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.17</version>
  </dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>3.8.1</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
  <pluginManagement>
  <plugins>
      <plugin>
          <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
          <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <configuration>
                  <server>apache-tomcat-7.0.25</server>
                  <url>http://localhost:8080/manager</url>
                  <path>/</path>
              </configuration>
          </plugin>
      </plugins>
  </pluginManagement>
```

Could you please tell me the my fault or suggest a article where I can find the explanation of this?

Comment: try changing thi <url>http://maven.apache.org</url> to <url>http://localhost:serverport/MyApp</url>

Comment: Is this a web application? If it is, the `<packaging>` element should have the value `war`. And probably you want to add the jetty or tomcat maven plugin.

Comment: Thanks Satya, but the issue remain

Comment: @Satya The `<url/>` tag has nothing to do with the web application url. It is merely *the URL of where the project lives*.

Comment: Thanks Augusto, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others mentioned, yo need a war packaging. To be sure, start your project with a maven archetype, see http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-webapp.html

```
mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=com.mycompany.app -DartifactId=my-webapp -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-webapp
```

Make sure you can build a war:

```
mvn clean install
```

Now import your project in IDEA: File, New Project, Import Project from external Model, Maven, select your pom.xml.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have got a MojoException when execute mvn archetype, but sadly it didn't contain a clear message what I forgot to add. However, mvn clean install give a success build.

Comment: But it doesn't fix the issue.

Comment: If mvn archetype didn't work, I would definitely check and fix my maven configuration before going further. Did you create a new project from existing external maven model? After that you need a new Run Configuration, where you define the application context of the app, default is /. The URL must match, or 404 will follow.

Comment: Yes, I did exactly what you say, but I didn't work. I havr modified the pom in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Not so sure about idea, but typically a web project will have packaging type of war, rather than jar.

Also research the maven war plugin so you know which files to add and into which folders.

You could research this by creating a sample app by using a maven archetype. Then use a tool to compare the sample source and your own.

Answer (score 0):

If you have 404 I guess the problem is with URL you try to access to your app.

Nonetheless check the content of your artifact and libs (Ctrl+Shift+Alt+s).
Also, try to add such maven plugins as `maven-compiler-plugin` and `maven-war-plugin` to your `pom.xml`.

Comment: Why should he add those plugins? It doesn't make sense to just ask him to include these plugins without any further clarifications.

Comment: Well, I have added this new plugins, but IDE marks them as errors - it couldn't find them in directory/ I run synchronization with repo1.maven.con but it's stil updating.